# I am trying to make a desktop notifier

Tags: python, desktop-application

```
import time
from plyer import notification
import plyer


while True:
    notification.notify(
        title = "Please drink water",
        message ="Please Drink water",
        app_icon = "D:\Documents\Coding\Python\icon.ico",
        timeout= 1
            )
        #   time.sleep(6)
        time.sleep(6)
```

this is not working, any suggestions

there are a lot of bugs in it apparently

Comment: try removing icon. Cause if I add that that wouldn't worked for me

Comment: what if i want to add a icon though

Comment: sorry for late reply. Do you got an error of  `raise Exception('Could not load icon {}'.format(app_icon))`?

Answer (score 0):

There can be one error as this

```
Exception: Could not load icon P:/People files/water glass.ico
```

Why this can come:-

1. When you changed .png, .jpg or any type of image extension to .ico manually as plyer only support .ico
2. .ico file is exported by paint or a software using save as in .bmp

So you can't load that icon. What you can do is to go in any website that gives .ico files and download that. Don't overwrite your old image. Either delete old image or provide a new name to downloaded image.

Comment: remove the icon does'nt make a difference and i cannot see the error because my computer lags at the time of the running of the code

Comment: do you see something in top right corner of notification button? if you are in windows

Comment: it is somthing self exception

Comment: have you tried with 'r' prefix before string path?